# If I choose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10", will it install itself into the unallocated space I made?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I Want to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10 and if I choose that option I mentioned above, will it use my unallocated space I shrunk earlier or will it shrink the c drive again? And if it shrinks it again, how much space will Ubuntu take then? (I have a 256 GB SSD) And I have UEFI, will that matter in this Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu does not automatically shrink partition. If you choose the option to install alongside, the installer will show you a slider and you will have to decide how much to allocate. You may also get an option to install in the free (unallocated) space.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it will shrink the C drive again. That's what the [Ubuntu wiki page on dual booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot?action=show&redirect=DualBoot%2FWindows) suggests will happen, and it says that this option is not recommended. Choose the custom partitioning and install it onto the empty space.